# Can a miner receive mining rewards?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a block in my chain that was a mined by a contract. Is this valid data and a common scenario?

Here's the address of the miner: https://etherscan.io/address/0x2c118f3016c44236c36b1a7f049ddb0d8de76a28

`{"difficulty"=>"0xfde159cb00d",
 "extraData"=>"0xd783010400844765746887676f312e352e31856c696e7578",
 "gasLimit"=>"0x47e7c4",
 "gasUsed"=>"0x19a28",
 "hash"=>"0xa63675ab5af7add5b7a8ea0073b55149a088652bb2010c85917d5d35849b7d17",
 "logsBloom"=>
  "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
 "miner"=>"0x2c118f3016c44236c36b1a7f049ddb0d8de76a28",
 "mixHash"=>
  "0xc1d9dff2fe99ed74f500365bba34f7dd623c3c93f8403560c194f9140c00c553",
 "nonce"=>"0x0c6b0f48d3f19a15",
 "number"=>"0x11a2ef",
 "parentHash"=>
  "0x8a7738e06e7c15a599ac41b30c28f880647541dc81336a9afdc13c53be24d15a",
 "receiptsRoot"=>
  "0xc5b0f98df6ed0ce43ad8d2f99e3bfea5a4667c75cfec27d1192a209143780521",
 "sha3Uncles"=>
  "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
 "size"=>"0x453",
 "stateRoot"=>
  "0xc40e881d3eaeee00990f5da64141fa6adc6e93b611577bcffcbf2a563b9b4d48",
 "timestamp"=>"0x56e85aec",
 "totalDifficulty"=>"0x8436a3199129d655",
 "transactions"=>
  [{"blockHash"=>
     "0xa63675ab5af7add5b7a8ea0073b55149a088652bb2010c85917d5d35849b7d17",
    "blockNumber"=>"0x11a2ef",
    "from"=>"0x5c67d94468c06c92e2d5f8446c41e7a859377994",
    "gas"=>"0x5208",
    "gasPrice"=>"0x6fc23ac00",
    "hash"=>
     "0x7a1b9c24f3052cd7b8deaadcf906d4ba6028bb25031f31453b4971d40a882db0",
    "input"=>"0x",
    "nonce"=>"0x1f8",
    "to"=>"0x32be343b94f860124dc4fee278fdcbd38c102d88",
    "transactionIndex"=>"0x0",
    "value"=>"0xfaaac612e666c00",
    "v"=>"0x1c",
    "r"=>"0xe53bc49ec56ac95a3e53eae9e83666289e7b868407cc66e914aa755bdbe7c508",
    "s"=>"0x24ae889e50907ab00cffe8dd6e841ce2fefd455aac9afa02b61613f0c4a35c38"},
   {"blockHash"=>
     "0xa63675ab5af7add5b7a8ea0073b55149a088652bb2010c85917d5d35849b7d17",
    "blockNumber"=>"0x11a2ef",
    "from"=>"0x6d8ade29f7519e1e9a1198b85e6d6d5c425ff7a9",
    "gas"=>"0x5208",
    "gasPrice"=>"0x6fc23ac00",
    "hash"=>
     "0xc25a3653ed1825c4550402ed7a564943b1b7a35e3ef109854308276f0283f121",
    "input"=>"0x",
    "nonce"=>"0x130",
    "to"=>"0x32be343b94f860124dc4fee278fdcbd38c102d88",
    "transactionIndex"=>"0x1",
    "value"=>"0xf64891250eb5000",
    "v"=>"0x1c",
    "r"=>"0x91c3cd0e1f629220f88728876dc22bc5905e5b4af02055761ca80b37bcb70991",
    "s"=>"0x30d5163de8b61a3d0e453b18bb09ad19c82d6b5d9629ff38d583ad576cd0043d"},
   {"blockHash"=>
     "0xa63675ab5af7add5b7a8ea0073b55149a088652bb2010c85917d5d35849b7d17",
    "blockNumber"=>"0x11a2ef",
    "from"=>"0x1e0cf4971f42462823b122a9a0a2206902b51132",
    "gas"=>"0x5208",
    "gasPrice"=>"0x6fc23ac00",
    "hash"=>
     "0xea93760e08b425b1570af60edd13290d81e002cadcdc0b971bb485cc0df3c523",
    "input"=>"0x",
    "nonce"=>"0x608",
    "to"=>"0x32be343b94f860124dc4fee278fdcbd38c102d88",
    "transactionIndex"=>"0x2",
    "value"=>"0xe4f24e15ac16c00",
    "v"=>"0x1b",
    "r"=>"0x2a921ec568abe637e64627485eaf7bbe047b99aabac1cb95b6b1ff2edf42571e",
    "s"=>"0x3eb5429f10368e2c1e6cec899e33c64b3d08a7a84b8c343a146b2c5d43066772"},
   {"blockHash"=>
     "0xa63675ab5af7add5b7a8ea0073b55149a088652bb2010c85917d5d35849b7d17",
    "blockNumber"=>"0x11a2ef",
    "from"=>"0xc756fdfa89ad940c7690d7bf1720e5591327add4",
    "gas"=>"0x5208",
    "gasPrice"=>"0x6fc23ac00",
    "hash"=>
     "0x99376128060e7a167712d5b5dca19ec4f455d134327a08ae06eaab3e1ee416c8",
    "input"=>"0x",
    "nonce"=>"0x15b",
    "to"=>"0x32be343b94f860124dc4fee278fdcbd38c102d88",
    "transactionIndex"=>"0x3",
    "value"=>"0xfabdb60b5ce9800",
    "v"=>"0x1b",
    "r"=>"0x8f75e40981abe4698b156cd3f20a3f6ce7970eddb98d050f6493f11471aa3dac",
    "s"=>"0x2672f8d93df71123a91c61b597208eea273fd6b5d5eed26080899a933ce10f61"},
   {"blockHash"=>
     "0xa63675ab5af7add5b7a8ea0073b55149a088652bb2010c85917d5d35849b7d17",
    "blockNumber"=>"0x11a2ef",
    "from"=>"0x151255dd9e38e44db38ea06ec66d0d113d6cbe37",
    "gas"=>"0x15f90",
    "gasPrice"=>"0x4a817c800",
    "hash"=>
     "0xf83a970fcbc3620e5210ccc32229592ba7497614aec09404e02265722d3d69ea",
    "input"=>"0x",
    "nonce"=>"0xd0b",
    "to"=>"0xbcf94244c7fe9395f5c3d46c6feb09ad43a49ff7",
    "transactionIndex"=>"0x4",
    "value"=>"0xee74c2326392c00",
    "v"=>"0x1c",
    "r"=>"0x5d9b0ffaeffa0928df2f1f3bdcd81722200f43f3e24c64ca15c7db87099b651f",
    "s"=>
     "0x2a465e6f8db72402fcf8c1747116e3c044d75f50fda546d73d1fc4c2077e5bab"}],
 "transactionsRoot"=>
  "0x4edf3b133f0b29b88f82e9c607cd6b9d12627e80736c496049036c68773546d8",
 "uncles"=>[]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The miner (usually a person running software on a machine) can specify any address they'd like to receive the block reward. Specifically, they can also specify a contract (e.g. if they want to use a multisig wallet for the rewards).

Comment: Thanks. So the `miner` field in the block data entry represents where the reward for the mining will go to?

Comment: That's right. From https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetblock :

miner: String, 20 Bytes - the address of the beneficiary to whom the mining rewards were given.